# PyInstaller can't find data file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a .spec file for my project, and PyInstaller runs without a hitch. However, on running the .exe, my loader hiccups with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "../../pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in importHook

  File "../../pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\workspace\nifty-prose-articulator\build\pyi.win32\Nifty
 Prose Articulator\out00-PYZ.pyz\src.gui.main_window", line 25, in <module>
  File "../../pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in importHook

  File "../../pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\workspace\nifty-prose-articulator\build\pyi.win32\Nifty
 Prose Articulator\out00-PYZ.pyz\src.docx", line 15, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Spencer\\workspace\\ni
fty-prose-articulator\\build\\pyi.win32\\Nifty Prose Articulator\\out00-PYZ.pyz\
\OMMLToMathML.xsl'
```

Besides the XSLT it is referring to, I also need to load in other XML files at runtime.

Here is my .spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['src/main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Spencer\\workspace\\nifty-prose-articulator'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=1,
          name=os.path.join('build\\pyi.win32\\Nifty Prose Articulator', 'Nifty Prose Articulator.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas + [('OMMLToMathML.xsl', 'C:\\Users\\Spencer\\workspace\\nifty-prose-articulator\\src\\docx\\OMMLToMathML.xsl', 'DATA')] ,
               Tree(os.path.abspath('src/forms/icons')),
               Tree(os.path.abspath('src/docx')),
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name=os.path.join('dist', 'Nifty Prose Articulator'))
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name=os.path.join('dist', 'Nifty Prose Articulator.app'))
```

The `OMMLToMathML.xsl` is inside `C:\Users\Spencer\workspace\nifty-prose-articulator\src\docx`.

The .spec is in `C:\Users\Spencer\workspace\nifty-prose-articulator\Nifty Prose Articulator.spec`.

The command I used to create the .exe is this: `python ../../pyinstaller-2.0/utils/Build.py "Nifty Prose Articulator.spec"`

As you can see, I have tried adding the file individually and by adding it implicitly using a `Tree` (which also had some other data files).

I must be doing something wrong, but I have been banging my head on this for too long. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that that particular stylesheet came from some deprecated code that I forgot to remove. Everything else works fine.